# Creating an animation sequence with CSS and animation-delay

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to create a CSS animation with 6 grey divs where each div sequentially turns yellow one at a time and stays yellow until the last one is complete then the whole animation reverses, with the last div turning back to grey one at a time in reverse until its back to its original state. I'd like this to continue infinitely. The code I have is using an `animation-delay` to try to create this sequence but I end up with all the divs infinitely flashing yellow. How can I achieve the result I'm looking for?

```
  <div class="container">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
  </div>
```

--

```
.container {
      display: flex;
      gap: 1vmin;
      width: 12vmin;
      height: 5vmin;
  }

  div {
      width: 2vmin;
      height: 5vmin;
      background: #C7C7C7;

      &:first-child {
        animation: flash 1s linear infinite alternate;
        animation-delay: 1s;
      }

      &:nth-child(2) {
        animation: flash 1s linear infinite alternate;
        animation-delay: 2s;
      }

      &:nth-child(3) {
        animation: flash 1s linear infinite alternate;
        animation-delay: 3s;
      }

      &:nth-child(4) {
        animation: flash 1s linear infinite alternate;
        animation-delay: 4s;
      }

      &:nth-child(5) {
        animation: flash 1s linear infinite alternate;
        animation-delay: 5s;
      }

      &:nth-child(6) {
        animation: flash 1s linear infinite alternate;
        animation-delay: 6s;
      }

      @keyframes flash {
        0% {
            background: #C7C7C7;
        }

        100% {
            background: yellow;
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: You can't do that with animations that are all just one second long. I am not even sure if you can do it with just one keyframe shared between all of them.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I could do it?

Comment: I'd start by drawing this onto a piece of paper ... six lines, one for each div, and then you divide them into "intervals" of a second each, and then you color in what div needs to be in what stage in what interval. And then try and determine what animations, with what delays, you need where ...